# Which is more efficient (resource wise) way to load multiple images in layers? - Load and Compile PHP or Just stack them?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have folder of images, it's basically drawn character with: Skin, Eyes, Hair, Facial Expression, Pants, Shirt, Shoes. Each user's character set is stored in database in following format. For example:

> wbghbwb

Each letter indicates which item is loaded, in this case it's:

> white skin base, blue eyes, grey hair, happy expression, black pants, white shirt and brown shoes.

I am now going to make a function that will accept the character code and return image, so my question is which is the more efficient (resource wise) method?

1) Load all layers and using PHP GD put all layers into one image and store it on server (when user registers and customizes his character, so his character is stored on server as .png then just load it)

2) Load all layers and just stack them on each other and using CSS format so it looks like whole character but doesn't store anything on server? So technically there would be about 7 layers loaded and stacked together.

I know first method will require additional storage space, but would 2nd method not slow down server? Would it not take more bandwith loading all layers?

Note: Each layer is about 16kb.

Comment: Are you rendering in a browser? If so, maybe consider SVG too, as it is scalable.

Comment: @halfer yes it's a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer, just which resource you want to optimize. I.e.

Option 1 duplicates disk storage of the image layers and adds minor processing to the server, but by doing this you may save on network latency when you transport the combined images. Depending on whether you lazy "compile" the image stacks gives you additional flexibility.

Option 2 optimizes data storage of the layers on server because you no longer have to "precompile" the image stacks into all permutations of layers on the server.

So, as to your question of slowing down the server, you would have to measure to be sure, but if we're going to speculate, again it's whether the processing of synthesizing a new image out of several components pieces is slower than the several network requests that would be needed to fetch the component pieces to be assembled on the client.

Sometimes it's not just raw performance comparisons that matter. The perceived performance can be just as and more important and can allow you to be more flexible in your design.